# install4j - How to set Compiler Variables programmatically?

Tags: install4j

I know Installer Variables can be set programmatically.
But, I see no setCompilerVariables() method ....

I want to change which component to install based on user selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler variables are fixed at compile-time, they cannot be changed at runtime. Variables that are "variable" in the installer are called "installer variables" in install4j. This is a different concept. For more on the different variable systems, see [here](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/variables.html).

> I want to change which component to install based on user selection.

This is unrelated to compiler variables. With the API, you make a call like

```
context.getInstallationComponentById("myId").setSelected(true);
```

to change the selection state of an installation component.